# NodeJS async/await

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

I have the following code

```
removeApps: async () => {
    common.header('Remove Apps')
    const value = await inquirer.removeAppsList();      
    value.removeAppsList.forEach(async (element) => {
       await shellExec('adb shell pm uninstall -k --user 0 ' + element).then(async function (result) {
            console.log('Removing ' + element + ' - ' + result.stdout)
        }).catch()
    });
    console.log('complete')
},
```

The forEach loops over the array and processes all the values in the array, after that is complete I want to console.log('complete') but the "Complete" is being printed before the forEach has started?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of a `forEach` callback, use a `for` loop, so that you remain in the outer `async` function, and multiple `await` will be awaited for, one after the other:

```
for (let element of value.removeAppsList) {
    await shellExec('adb shell pm uninstall -k --user 0 ' + element).then(function (result) {
        console.log('Removing ' + element + ' - ' + result.stdout);
    });
}
```

And don't use `async` as `then` callback function. You only need `async` when you plan to use `await` within that function.

Remember that when you call an `async` function, it returns at the very moment it processes an `await`. It doesn't wait before returning. But once the awaited promise resolves, (and the callstack is empty) that function context restores, and execution continues until the next `await`, ...etc.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) if you don't want to wait for each promise to resolve before calling the next one.

`Promise.all` will reject as soon as one of the promises inside the array rejects, if you don't want that you can use [Promise.allSettled](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled) or add a `.catch` on the returned promise.

```js
removeApps: async () => {
  common.header('Remove Apps')
  const value = await inquirer.removeAppsList()

  await Promise.all(
    value.removeAppsList.map(element =>
      shellExec('adb shell pm uninstall -k --user 0 ' + element).then(res =>
        console.log('Removing ' + element + ' - ' + result.stdout),
      ),
    ),
  )

  console.log('complete')
}
```